# Import style file doesn’t scoped?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2

when I try to import CSS file like this, the CSS doesn't scoped.

must write style in style tag that can be work ???

I use the vue-cli to try this

```
<style scoped>
   @import "hell.css";
</style>
```

Comment: Same question with answer: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/import-style-file-doesnt-scoped/7479

Comment: yaa But it's not working.@Phil

Comment: you need to use preprocessors so they recompile the style

Answer (score 1):

As Phil mentioned try that,

> As best I can tell, `<style scoped>` has been removed from the specs and
> even browsers that were supporting it have pulled it.

[image]